# How to handle events on SharePoint controls?

Tags: custom-list, people-picker, events, field-controls

I have a custom list in which there is a people picker control and a taxonomy control. I want the taxonomy control to be filled automatically whenever any user is filled in the people control.

Scenario for example:

If I enter user A in the people picker his relative information stored in the user profile property should be fetched and filled in the taxonomy control.

To do this, I need to handle the LostFocus() event of the people picker control.

Is it possible to handle such event? If yes, then please provide some guidance or reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my view doing this auto fill up thing should go on server side so that you have much control.

You can hide the field input for "Taxonomy" on New and Update form.
Now you can use Event Receiver or Workflow to update the  "Taxonomy" field on item "Added" and "Updated"

Comment: In this case I agree, but there are quite a lot of scenarios where client side is the way to go, using for example SPServices :)

Comment: then need to figure out how to find which users are selected in PeoplePicker control and I guess this require little bit of research. Also have to bind events on focus and blur to that control and then update the "Taxonomy" control properly. Whole process is research job :)

Comment: I went through some research and found that the event capturing on control is possible using jquery and we should pass the JSLink in the new form. So, how is it possible to capture the focusout event of people picker control? If any reference is there then provide.. @RobertLindgren

Comment: It needs to be figure out actually. Which version of SharePoint are you using? 2010 or 2013?